# Sorting and counting unknown strings in R

Tags: r, string, sorting, char

I have a very extensive dataset organized in rows, each carrying hundreds of characters. The original Excel file was transformed to .csv with commas used as delimiters, then imported to R. Every row is recognized as a vector, I can select specific rows, browse, etc.
Here's the example of what I have:

```
115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";
116,"MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10";
117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";
118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";
```

As you can see, in every vector(row) there are 6 fields divided by commas. I am interested in extracting some specific unknown values from the field 5 and counting the number of occurencies of every value starting with §... sign. In fact, this data are personal records of felons found guilty by the Juvenile Court. Field 5 includes, among other unnecessary information, paragraphs from the Criminal Law. I would like to count the paragraphs and to summarize the info into the table like this:

```
number           Person         Paragraphs     Occurencies          
 116             MC3RIQeDk6k    §36              2
                                §250ad           1
                                §177b            1
 117             TT3Z1ralU7F    §29f             2
                                §2               3
                                §13              1
                                §671c            1
```

The problem is I don't know which paragraphs are going to appear in every row so I cannot search for a known criteria.
I would be very thankful if someone could find any solution to this problem.

Comment: Is this `115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";`**one** string or separate strings?

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann This is one string, in .csv file all of this sits in the first column in one cell.

Comment: Okay, then my solution should work. Does it?

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann yes, it seem to work, thanks. It is 11:30 AM here in NY, I am going to run your solution on all the data, it should take hours, I guess. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Please see edited solution.

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann actually, I liked the old version more, now I can hardly guess what paragraph corresponds to what occurency. I understand and like your idea of splitting (multiplying) rows by the number of paragraphs appearing in field 5, but now to comprehend the relationships I should rollback to the original data and count paragraphs by their appearance. In my opinion, your original solution was more elegant. Nevertheless, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Do feel free to use the first solution rather than the second.

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann it is not there anymore. I really liked your step by step explanations and temporary data outputs in the middle.

Comment: Can't you find it on your console?

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann Cleaned it to paste your edited solution. Never mind.

Comment: I've edited the solution again (think you'll like it too). Can you work with it?

Comment: I've corrected a mistake in the code. It should work now. Does it?

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann I used your second solution and put it on test. First, I extracted a bunch of rows (20, I think) and performed your analysis routine on them. Worked like a charm. Of course, one should go back and review the occur column to compare it to the paragraphs (i.e., to see what paragraph is on the first place in this row, what paragraph is on the second place etc.).Now it works on the first three datasets (each is about 100K rows), I am waiting for the program to end. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann but I don't understand your last updated version - how comes in the last column (occur) there are three leading zeros for the first inmate? This person was found guilty according to three paragraphs (§12, $175a and §155bc), I would expect to have three 1-s (i.e., he/she violated rules in paragraphs 12 (§12 was found once), 175a (§175a was found once) and 155bc (§155bc was also found once)). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're right. Let me take a look at that ...

Comment: Have updated the solution yet again. I think I got it right this time.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Outstanding, thanks a lot. Works on my sample. I won't abort the whole run (it still runs), but am going to implement your solution once the thing ends. I'll report you and the entire community on my results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your positive feedback and sorry for the multiple hickups.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann and all the community Your updated program works excellent, deepest respect and thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a trivial task but here's first go at it:

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c('115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";',
         '116,"MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10";',
         '117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";',
         '118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";')
)
```

To extract the relevant values, you need to use `str_extract` and, if there's more than one result per string, `str_extract_all`as well as lookaround:

```
df$numb <- str_extract(df$v1, '^\\d+(?=,)')
df$pers <- str_extract(df$v1, '(?<=,")\\w+(?=")')
df$para <- lapply(lapply(str_extract_all(df$v1, '§\\w+\\b'), unique), paste0, collapse = ",")

library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% separate_rows(para, sep = ",")
df2$occur <- str_count(df2$v1, paste(df2$para, "\\b", sep = ""))
```

Result:

```
df2
                                                                                       v1 numb        pers   para
1             115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";  115 RD3RW2rFoVF    §12
2             115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";  115 RD3RW2rFoVF  §175a
3             115,"RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09";  115 RD3RW2rFoVF §155bc
4        116,"MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10";  116 MC3RIQeDk6k    §36
5        116,"MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10";  116 MC3RIQeDk6k §250ad
6        116,"MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10";  116 MC3RIQeDk6k  §177b
7  117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";  117 TT3Z1ralU7F   §29f
8  117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";  117 TT3Z1ralU7F     §2
9  117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";  117 TT3Z1ralU7F    §13
10 117,"TT3Z1ralU7F","1","9965718496","§29f §2 §13 @assault §2 §2 §671c §29f","14:13:38";  117 TT3Z1ralU7F  §671c
11    118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";  118 QW3SlcwgU2d   §16b
12    118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";  118 QW3SlcwgU2d    §8a
13    118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";  118 QW3SlcwgU2d   §16a
14    118,"QW3SlcwgU2d","2","5972432856","@inc §16b §8a-c §16a §16b @road §22,"14:11:25";  118 QW3SlcwgU2d    §22
   occur
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      2
5      1
6      1
7      2
8      3
9      1
10     1
11     2
12     1
13     1
14     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data looks like Chris Ruehlemann's data. Using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`

```r
df %>%
  separate(col=v1, into=c("number", "Person","V3", "V4", "Information","V6"), "\"?,\"") %>%
  mutate(Paragraphs=str_split(Information, " |,")) %>%
  unnest(Paragraphs) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Paragraphs, "§")) %>%
  group_by(number, Person, Paragraphs) %>%
  summarise(Occurencies=n(), .groups="drop")
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   number Person      Paragraphs Occurencies
   <chr>  <chr>       <chr>            <int>
 1 115    RD3RW2rFoVF §12                  1
 2 115    RD3RW2rFoVF §155bc               1
 3 115    RD3RW2rFoVF §175a                1
 4 116    MC3RIQeDk6k §177b                1
 5 116    MC3RIQeDk6k §250ad               1
 6 116    MC3RIQeDk6k §36                  2
 7 117    TT3Z1ralU7F §13                  1
 8 117    TT3Z1ralU7F §2                   3
 9 117    TT3Z1ralU7F §29f                 2
10 117    TT3Z1ralU7F §671c                1
11 118    QW3SlcwgU2d §16a                 1
12 118    QW3SlcwgU2d §16b                 2
13 118    QW3SlcwgU2d §22                  1
14 118    QW3SlcwgU2d §8a-c                1
```

Comment: OP's data is structured differently than the data you start out from. See comments above.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Thanks for the hint. I adjusted the answer.

Comment: @Martin Gal Thanks for your solution.  I run it on a small sample as well. Unfortunately, it did not build the table you mention with the warning "Expected 6 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1023562 rows". I used Chris's df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rows_df_n)) command, where rows_df_n is the import of my .csv file (in global environment panel I can see the description: rows_df_n - large character (1062 elements...), i.e. R recognizes it as one big character).

Comment: @kshtwork That's odd. Hard to tell without seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data:

```
d <- data.frame(rbind(c("RD3RW2rFoVF","0","1952869481","§12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc","14:18:09"),
                      c("MC3RIQeDk6k","82","7935904859","§36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b","14:16:10")),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(d)[4] <- "Paragraphs"
d
# X1 X2         X3                     Paragraphs       X5
# 1 RD3RW2rFoVF  0 1952869481     §12,§175a,@juvenile §155bc 14:18:09
# 2 MC3RIQeDk6k 82 7935904859 §36 §250ad §36 @criminal §177b 14:16:10
```

You can unnest the paragraphs like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

d %>%
  mutate(Paragraphs = str_extract_all(Paragraphs, "§\\d+[a-zA-Z]*")) %>% # search for §-sign, at least one digit and zero or more letters
  unnest(Paragraphs) %>%
  group_by(X1, Paragraphs) %>% # check groups
  add_tally(name = "occurancies") %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 7 x 6
# X1          X2    X3         Paragraphs X5       occurancies
# <chr>       <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <int>
#   1 RD3RW2rFoVF 0     1952869481 §12        14:18:09           1
# 2 RD3RW2rFoVF 0     1952869481 §175a      14:18:09           1
# 3 RD3RW2rFoVF 0     1952869481 §155bc     14:18:09           1
# 4 MC3RIQeDk6k 82    7935904859 §36        14:16:10           2
# 5 MC3RIQeDk6k 82    7935904859 §250ad     14:16:10           1
# 6 MC3RIQeDk6k 82    7935904859 §36        14:16:10           2
# 7 MC3RIQeDk6k 82    7935904859 §177b      14:16:10           1
```

Comment: OP's data has different structure than the data you start out from.

Comment: You mean the rownames?